# is there a method to group list in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like :

```
n° , list_code
1    ["AR13","BD34","TA42","LK87"]
2    ["KA54","OP98"]
1    ["LA14","LK87","AR13"]
3    ["GH53"]
2    ["LO54","LP87"]
```

i want to have an output like :

```
n° ,  list_code 
1     ["AR13","BD34","TA42","LK87","LA14","LK87","AR13"]
2     ["KA54","OP98","LO54","LP87"]
3     ["GH53"]
```

so i want to groupby "n°" and concatenate lists , then we should display for each row the number of occurences of each code  like :

```
n° ,  list_code                                              , output_final
1     ["AR13","BD34","TA42","LK87","LA14","LK87","AR13"]     , {"AR13":2,"BD34":1,"TA42":1,"LK87":2 ..}
2     ["KA54","OP98","LO54","LP87"]                          , {"KA54":1,"OP98":1 ...}
3     ["GH53"]                                                , {"GH53":1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for flatten and then [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
#if necessary convert strings to lists
import ast
df['list_code'] = df['list_code'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

---

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

df = df.groupby('n°')['list_code'].agg(lambda x: list(chain(*x))).reset_index()
df['output_final'] = df['list_code'].apply(Counter)
print (df)
   n°                                   list_code  \
0   1  [AR13, BD34, TA42, LK87, LA14, LK87, AR13]   
1   2                    [KA54, OP98, LO54, LP87]   
2   3                                      [GH53]   

                                        output_final  
0  {'AR13': 2, 'BD34': 1, 'TA42': 1, 'LK87': 2, '...  
1       {'KA54': 1, 'OP98': 1, 'LO54': 1, 'LP87': 1}  
2                                        {'GH53': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it but without importing more things:

```
df.set_index("n°")\
  .list_code\
  .explode()\
  .groupby(level=0)\
  .agg(lambda x: dict(zip(x, x.value_counts())))

n°
1    {'AR13': 2, 'BD34': 2, 'TA42': 1, 'LK87': 1, '...
2         {'KA54': 1, 'OP98': 1, 'LO54': 1, 'LP87': 1}
3                                          {'GH53': 1}
Name: list_code, dtype: object
```

Disclaimer: I'm pretty sure this is slower than [@jezrael solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66850968/13743233).